# Force file download from Arduino website

Tags: html, ajax, arduino

At the moment I'm hosting a simple HTML website with Javascript (JQuery and Bootstrap) on my Arduino. Now I want to let the user download a .txt log file from the Arduino to his brwoser. The user has to click on the following button.

```
<button type="button" onclick="downLog()" class="btn btn-success">Download Log</button>
```

I know that for security reasons Javascript is not allowed to interact with your hard drive. So saving the file after it get's back from an Ajax call is not possible. So I was thinking about sending the correct header from my Arduino to my client so the download can start.

```
File temp = SD.open("log.txt", FILE_READ);
if(temp) {
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
  client.println("Content-Disposition: attachment;");
  client.print("Content-Length: ");
  client.println(temp.size());

  while(temp.available()) {
    char a = temp.read();
    client.print(a);
  }

  temp.close();
}
```

But this doens't seem to work. I have this from the [Arduino forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,178204.0.html) but for me it doesn't work. Any ideas why? I have tested the connection, my client connects successful to the Arduino, the file is opened and my client gets a successful response back. But no download starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project, that I needed just to connect to the arduino's IP address to commence the download, I couldn't make it work 'till I wrote:

```
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Content-Type: text/text");
client.println("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"test.txt\"");
client.println("Connection: close");
```

Hope it helps!